# How to rename Parent UIViewController title from Child UIViewController iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, title, uinavigationitem

I am working in `UITabBarController` based iPhone app. My app having *5 taps*. In my 4th tap UIViewController having one Child `UIViewController`. My First `RootViewController` screen title is "All Messages". My second UIViewController name is "Conversations".

The screen flow is **tap 4 -> All Messages -> Conversation**

All Messages contains `UITableView` so if the user clicks any message from tableview we are taking the user to Conversation screen (`UIViewController`). This screen shows particular users messages.

**From this child UIViewController I have to update Parent viewController's title name form "All Messages" to "New Messages(1)" and also the back button name should change from "All Messages" to "New Messages(1)"**

I have followed the below code to update the screen title. This code is in my Child view controller named Conversation screen.

```
AllMessagesViewController *mesViewController = [[AllMessagesViewController alloc] init];
mesViewController.navigationItem.title = @"New Messages(1)";
```

Anyone please help me where am doing wrong? This approach is correct? Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `NSNotificationCenter`.

In `AllMessagesViewController` declare a method:

```
- (void)changeTitle:(NSString *)newTitle;
```

and then register the view controller for a notification event

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                             selector:@selector(changeTitle:) 
                                name:@"ChangeTitleEvent" object:nil];
```

Then when you want to change the title from `ConversationViewController` send a notify:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeTitleEvent"
                                               object:@"New Message (1)"];
```

This method will call `changeTitle:` method in `AllMessagesViewController` so you just change the title using the parameter `newTitle`:

```
- (void)changeTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
{
   self.title = newTitle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check this. I have one doubt. If i update the parent viewcontroller name like this will the back button name change or not? Could you please clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: You only have to try... I suppose that because the back button contains the name of parent, then if the parent's name change so change the back button's title too.

Comment: Thank you so much friend. Let me try. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSArray *arrControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
if([[arrControllers objectAtIndex:[arrControllers count]-2] isKindOfClass:[AllMessagesViewController class]])
{
  AllMessagesViewController *objAllMessagesViewController = (AllMessagesViewController *)[arrControllers objectAtIndex:[arrControllers count]-2];
  objAllMessagesViewController.title = @"New Messages(1)";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check this. I have one doubt. If i update the parent viewcontroller name like this will the back button name change or not? Could you please clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave your upvote for your help. Your answer also worked for me. Thanks again.